# Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'transformClassesWithDexForDebug' property 'streamOutputFolder' during up-to-date check. >

Tags: android-studio

Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'transformClassesWithDexForDebug' property 'streamOutputFolder' during up-to-date check.

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplications\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10000\instant-run_a8936017f31503754089f70c92a385611dceec11\classes.dex'.